# how to pre-train a CNN to pass the CNN weights to LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

how to pre-train a CNN to pass the CNN weights to LSTM?

For example I have a model like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(None,2,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: What do you mean pass the CNN weights to LSTM? CNNs and LSTMs are very different and you can't just pass weights between them.

Comment: Sorry. I mean train the CNN part only, freeze last layer (usually the dense layer) and then  load the model and then on top put a LSTM.